# Using strtr inside a preg_replace?

Tags: php, preg-replace, strtr

I'd like to reformat a `preg_replace()` match with `strtr()` inside the preg_replace. 
Is it possible ?

I did the following:

```
$array = array("#" => "_", "/" => "-");
$output = preg_replace($regex, '<span>'.strtr('$0', $array).'</span>', $input);
```

In my example Z# (which corresponds to my `preg_replace` match, $0 in the `strtr`) should become Z_, but nothing happens.

Thank you !

*nb. $regex is a regular expression matching some portions of $input, it works.*

Comment: That's not possible because `'$0'` inside `strtr` is not part of the `preg_replace` replacement string, just part of the haystack of `strtr`, so it's _literally_ `'$0'`...why don't you put `strtr` outside `preg_replace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **e**-modifier:

```
$output = preg_replace('/$regex/e', '"<span>".strtr("$0", $array)."</span>"', $input);
```

Comment: no, no, no. don't do that. the `e` modifer basically turns `preg_replace()` into an `eval()`. That's a whole bunch of bad ideas all rolled into one.

Comment: no, no, no....don't won't to read those phrases everytime someone hears something about "eval"

Comment: thanks DR.Molle but doing this I get this error :
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' .... : regexp code on line 1`
Followed by :

`Fatal error: preg_replace() [<a href='function.preg-replace'>function.preg-replace</a>]: Failed evaluating code: &lt;span`

Comment: Works for me: http://codepad.org/OXkyjDF6 . It's important to use the single-quotes outside. See the difference when you switch the quotes: http://codepad.org/kt95k4Y8

Comment: Wonderful it works ! I had an eval error because of a bad single/double quotes mix. thanks a lot !